# Как сделать функцию на Python корректной?

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
var f = prompt();
var output = cToF(f);

function cToF(f) {
 c = 5 / 9 * (f - 32);
 console.log(c)
}
```

Стараюсь ту же функцию сделать на Python:

```
f = int(input())

def main(f):
    c = 5/9*(f-32)
print(c) #> выдает ошибку
```

Я пробовал добавить:

```
global c
```

но тоже не работает!
Как исправить, подскажите?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [6]: def foo(f):
   ...:     return 5 / 9 * (f - 32)
   ...:

In [7]: print(foo(10))
-12.222222222222223
```

Answer (score 2):

Если так же, как в исходной функции, т.е. печатать результат в самой функции, то нужно добавить отступ, чтобы `print(c)` было в теле функции:

```
def cToF(f):
    c = 5/9*(f-32)
    print(c)
```

Answer (score -3):

нашел решение. Вот код:

```
x = 100
def f():
    print(x)
f()
print(x)
```

Что бы создать глобальную переменную, необходимо её создать вне области кода.

А почему, собственно, нельзя вызвать метод print внутри функции? 
Код:

```
f = int(input())


def main(f):
   c = 5/9*(f-32)
   print(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(f)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую еще раз!

Comment: Ух ты!!!Сейчас сделаю test!!!Благодарю!

Comment: Я не ставил "минус" за данный ответ, хотя и стоило бы. Использование глобальных переменных для таких целей вредно и нецелесообразно. Гораздо проще, понятнее и безопаснее сделать функцию, которая просто вернет посчитанное значение и показать автору вопроса как правильно пользоваться функциями

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Comment: @FormatC Ответы могут быть разные - опасные и вредные, а могут - безопасные и полезные.

Comment: @FormatC какой ответ такая и оценка.